# acceder a variable antes de funcion

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables

¿es posible acceder a esta variable?

```
  function prueva(){
  alert("esto es una prueva");
  }
  var p="hola mundo";
  p.prueva();
```

¿sera posible?, solo es una duda que quiero responder

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu consulta, me explicas, lo que entiendo es que quieres leer una variable antes de iniciar la función, pero `p.prueva();` esta mal, porque tratas de usar una funcion de p, la cual no existe.

Comment: ¿en que forma es correcto?

Comment: que es lo que deseas en realidad que se muestre hola mundo antes que esto es prueba?

Comment: si eso es lo que deseo

Comment: Hola. Creo que puedes avanzar mucho más leyendo: [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript) Está traducido al español (casi todo) es claro y tiene buenos ejemplos; y lo más importante **puedes ir a tu ritmo**.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es **pasar una variable como parámetro**.

Por ejemplo la siguiente función define la variable `mensaje` en su declaración:

```
function prueba(mensaje) {
    alert(mensaje);
}
```

Esa variable `mensaje` (el **parámetro** de la función) vive únicamente en el ámbito de la función (no existe afuera), pero permite pasar un valor al llamar a la función.

```
prueba('hola mundo');
```

Y ese valor se asignará a la variable (en este caso mostrando la alerta).

Ahora bien, se le puede pasar un valor literal o el valor asignado a otra variable:

```js
function prueba(mensaje) {
    alert(mensaje);
    alert('y acá termina la prueba');
}


var a = 'pasamos el valor de a como parámetro a la función';

prueba(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, la verdad no entiendo la razón de tu consulta, pero si deseas mostrarlo antes se me ocurre lo siguiente.

PD: Si tienes alguna duda te respondo sobre el código, si agregarías algo mas especifico podría complementar mi respuesta.

```js
var saluda = 'Hola mundo';
console.log(saluda);

function prueba(){
  console.log("Chau mundo");
}

prueba();
```